# MS planner add task

Tags: prioritization

I'm pretty sure there must be a simple answer to this:

In MS PLanner when I add a new task to a bucket how do I get the task to go to the bottom of the list rather than join at the top?

or

How do I reorganise tasks in a bucket with the oldest at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps. If it doesn't work let me know :)

Click on the task to select it.

Click on the "Move" button located in the task details pane.

In the drop-down menu, select "Move to Bottom" to move the task to the bottom of the list.